# API or lib to convert boundary boxes or single long lat to quadtile?

Tags: coordinates, tiles

I would like to store geo coordinates as OpenStreetMap [quadtiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/QuadTiles). Is there more doc somewhere than in the link above? Are there standard solutions to convert long / lat points and boundary boxes into their quadtile coordinates?
(I code in Java).

Comment: What's a quad tile?

Comment: added a link defining quad tiles.